# How do I find my two missing drive partitions?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, backup

This is slightly complicated, hopefully I'll describe it well enough to be understood.

So I'm using linux (Ubuntu), and I have a 2TB portable hard drive, and a 500GB main drive.

On the portable drive I had 3 partitions. The first was about 650GB, not exactly sure on the other two.

I had a bit of an emergency, and needed to exact a backup of the 500GB main drive that I'd made to another hard drive, using Redo Backup, but didn't want to overwrite the main drive on my machine, so, I decided to extract it to the 2TB portable drive, instead. Redo's recovery system isn't the most flexible, so I had to extract the full 500GB of backup and it's various partitions to the 2TB drive.

The problem was, was that I already had stuff on the 2TB drive, but it wasn't full, and I had room for the 500GB backup extraction, if I moved some stuff around. It wasn't particularly important stuff, so what i decided to do before doing this, was move the files on the first 650GB partition onto the later partitions, then delete this first partition, giving room for the 500GB backup extraction.

So, I ran the Redo back recovery, and sure enough, it recovered all the partitions to the first 500GB of the 2TB portable drive. Unfortunately, the two partitions in the second half of the drive had disappeared.

I have to say, this wasn't a massive surprise to me. I thought it was likely to happen, and it was a risk I was willing to take to get at the backup files I needed. Like I say, the stuff on those two partitions wasn't massively important, but at the same time, it would be a HUGE pain to bring all those files back together.

Of course as the backup has only extracted to the first 500GB, the partitions should be still there, lost in the sea of unallocated space after the 500GB. I have thought, also, that scanning the unallocated space, byte for byte or whatever, a partition might have some sort of fingerprint that could be found. A string of bytes that would identify it as the start of a drive partition and it's size, so it could be recreated?

So, is there a way to find and recover these two partitions? A free linux tool, perhaps? Or have I lost the partitions and files forever?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like what TestDisk does

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this question as being off-topic?

Comment: (If this was MBR-based, it sounds like you may have lost the MBR.  I believe GPT is similar enough to say the same.)  Partitions are just boundaries, really.  What you want are the filesystem volumes.  It does sound like those many be fully in tact.  Specifying the boundaries again is likely to fully restore them, untouched, safe.  Nice job explaining it.  There is software that will look for the start of the volumes.  You may want to search for finding the signature of the filesystem type (e.g., search for "find ext4 signature" or "find NTFS signature".)

Comment: It does look like @golimar's suggestion ought to work well.  Joyfully, the price for permission to use this software is zero.  http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step says to use the software's "Analyse" functionality.

Comment: @TOOGAM It wasn't me, looks on topic (possibly a duplicate?), but I suspect it was the *"A free linux tool, perhaps?"* that triggered someone's over-zealous "No seeking product recommendations!" instinct, even though that reason should really be reserved for "what's the fastest video card this week" type Q's. You have to use some type of software "product" to solve almost any software problem...

Comment: You might also find something here: https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-data-recovery.html